# Is it ok to wrap the whole code into "try ... except" as the last resort?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, I have a big application in python running on a server a few times per day and sometimes it crashes. I want, when it crashes, it at least to release all the resources such as db connection, file handlers, etc.

I've got some "try ... except" blocks in it, but who knows where it's going to crash next? It's possible it'll crash somewhere where the code isn't wrapped into "try ... except".

What's a recommended way to improve it? Should I wrap the whole script body into "try ... except" as the last resort? Or what?

Comment: This is a very broad theoretical question. Try adding the code or the skeleton of it and shed light on problematic areas in it. Currently the question in not specific at all.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable method of protection to me, but i'm no expert. Just remember that when it crashes, you should only release those resources and not try to continue execution as normal.

Comment: Yes it's possible - where there is code there are bugs :), Instead of 1 big `try-except` try to split your code into blocks and use `try-except` for each block it will also allow you to test your code...

Comment: The recommended way of improving it is to fix what is causing it to crash.

Comment: @ShacharSh This is the type of question that actually doesn't need code. It's general enough that it will apply to many people, but it's also a specific and targeted question.

Comment: "who knows where it's going to crash next?" - You should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the whole code with a try-catch is the most simple way but it doesn't fix the problem.

I think the best way is to find out the root cause of crash and take care of it even just print an error message and exit.

Answer (score 4):

AFAICT the CPython interpreter should actually free most resources by itself (and emit an error message with a full traceback) on unhandled exceptions - except possibly for badly written extension code (binary code interfaced with Python) that fails to correctly free resources on garbage collection.

This being said, most well-behaved Python apps do indeed have a "top-level" catch-all exception handler that takes care of cleaning up what can be (global db connections etc) and, most importantly, make sure the exception **and it's full traceback** are logged somewhere and notify the maintainers.

wrt/ properly releasing *locally* allocated resources (files etc), context managers are your friends, ie use

```
with open(...) as myfile: 
    code_that_may_crash(...)
```

As others already mentionned fixing the root problem is the better solution but sometimes you just can't because it's outside your code (network failure, disk full or suddenly crapping out, whatever...)

To sum it up:

1. wrt/ resources deallocation, your best bet is to use context managers whereever possible and let the CPython runtime takes care of the rest
2. it's ok (and can be a good idea) to have a top-level catch-all exception handler but it should mainly focus on error reporting and preferably reraise the exception.

Comment: so what are you saying?

Comment: When I wrap all the code into try...except, I'll need to get **the text** of the latest exception regardless of what an exception is, how can I do that? I haven't found a common, de-facto way to do that, only some hacks via the module "sys", but they don't always work.

Comment: there's no such thing as "the text of an exception". An exception get args, the first one is _usually_ a text message but it can be anything. And why would you "need" this anyway ? You don't need it for logging, and in a top-level exception handler there's not much more you can do with an exception - log it (using `logger.exception()` so you get the full traceback in your logs) and re-raise it.

Comment: You are of course free to accept whatever answer you like

Comment: yeah, that's true, and for this I'm gratefullllllll. yeahhhhhhh

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Really weird that OP was randomly hostile to you. That's so uncalled for. Anyway your answer is completely right since a context manager is the way to free up stuff if an error is hit. Wrapping the whole thing in `try/except` is still useful though as afaik it's the only way to write the error to a file on a headless long running thing (like my micropython board)